# Acrobat launch error after installing my software

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, adobe, acrobat, visual-c++-2010

I have been working on an MFC project recently. I generated it's installer using Deployment Project from Visual Studio 2010. The problem that I am facing is that when I install my software on a windows 7 system, the adobe reader on that system stops working and throws away an error dialog with following message "Acrobat failed to load core dll". As soon as I uninstall my software, adobe reader starts working again. This problem doesn't occur on every system. Could you point out what could cause such a problem?

Comment: Yeah, Acrobat can't load a core dll. I'd run Process Monitor and see which DLL it is trying to load.  Once you do that, you can also run Process Monitor on your installer to see which files it uninstalls and installs.

Comment: It could be useful if you told us what files exactly your software installs.